# Using PowerCLI to get a tag associated with ESXI Host

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I have started using VMWare's Tag to assist in my reporting and filtering using `powerCLI` as my scripting tool.  I have `tags` associated with both `VMs` and `Hosts`.

I can retrieve the tag associated with the `VMs` with script like this:

```
 Get-VM | Select Name,Guest,PowerState,VMHost,Tag,ResourcePool
```

Because `tag` is included as a returned attribute.

What I can't figure out is how to return the `tab` values from a Host or Datastore. Any ideas?  I would like to add it to the following script:

```
Get-VMHost | Get-View | Select Name, 
 @{N="Cluster";E={Get-Cluster -VMHost (Get-VMHost $_.Name)}},
 @{N="DataCenter";E={Get-Datacenter -VMHost (Get-VMHost $_.Name)}},
 @{N="Vendor";E={$_.Hardware.SystemInfo.Vendor}},
 @{N="Model";E={$_.Hardware.SystemInfo.Model}},
 @{N="CPU";E={$_.Hardware.CpuInfo.NumCpuPackages}},
 @{N="CORES";E={$_.Hardware.CpuInfo.NumCpuCores}},
 @{N="TotalMHZ";E={[math]::round($_.Hardware.CpuInfo.Hz / 1000000, 0)}},
 @{N="UsedMem (GB)";E={[math]::round($_.Summary.QuickStats.overallMemoryUsage/1000, 2)}}, 
 @{N="TotalMem (GB)";E={[math]::round($_.Hardware.MemorySize / 1000000000, 2)}} |
Export-Csv MyOutputFile.csv
```

Thanks as always.

Comment: That's interesting that you can get `tag` from `Get-VM` but not `Get-VMHost`, because `Get-VM` returns a `VirtualManchine` object, and that does not include a `tag` property, so it must be included by the `ExtensionData` or `CustomFields` properties that are included from the `InventoryItem` base object. The `Get-VMHost` cmdlet also includes those, so I would think that you could do the exact same thing there.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more efficient way, but adding a property like this should work

```
@{N="tag";E={(Get-Tagassignment -Entity $_.Name).Tag.Name}}
```

What PowerCLI & vCenter versions are you running? I'm not recreating the described `Get-VM | Select Tag` behavior with PowerCLI 6.5 & VC 5.5.